# counting number a certain word per line in a file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file looks like

**Old data**

```
alireza,mahdi,alireza,mohammad
alireza,olivia,amireza,hasan
alireza,alireza,alireza,alireza
```

**New data**

```
0.54:30.36:N    0.54:32.31:N     0.54:30.36:Y
0.54:30.36:Y    0.54:32.31:N     0.54:30.36:Y
0.54:30.36:N    0.54:32.31:N     0.54:30.36:Y
0.54:30.36:N    0.54:32.31:N     0.54:30.36:N
```

and I would like to count number of say, "Y" per line,

so the output would be

```
1
2
1
0
```

so I can grep it like `"grep -w ':Y' myfile" but then I don't know how to count it ! since wc ...

**UPDATE
I am sorry to change the data and possibly the pattern. I wanted to present a simple and understandable format which I was not successful. Again, I do apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your new data, you could simply change the field separator:

```
awk -F'[ :.]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i=="Y") c++;}}{print c; c=0}' inputfile
```

or make use of a pattern to match against:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~/:Y$/) c++;}}{print c; c=0}' inputfile
```

Both would yield:

```
1
2
1
0
```

for your *new* input.

---

*Old answer:* You could use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i=="alireza") c++;}}{print c; c=0}' inputfile
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
2
1
4
0
```

Comment: oh I am sorry - I have simplified my question wrongly, can I update it ! since the data structure I am dealing with is complicated and I wanted to make it simple.

Comment: @user702846 Post realistic data to begin with.  You don't seem new enough to be told that.

Comment: Here is midnight and I feel stupid; sorry about data.

Comment: @user702846 Changing the field separator should work.  Refer to the edit above.

Answer (score 6):

This is the idiomatic awk way to print how may times a RE occurs on each line:

```
$ awk '{print gsub(/:Y/,"")}' file
1
2
1
0
```